# Is it possible to have parent and child collections with Eleventy (11ty)?

Tags: javascript, html, handlebars.js, liquid, eleventy

I'd like to be able to have parent and child collections using [Eleventy](https://www.11ty.io/), which I can then loop through to create navigation.

I currently have some posts with in a collection called `continents`, with the front matter displayed like this:

```
---
title: Europe
tags: continents
---
```

Which I loop through to create a list of links:

```
<ul class="parent-list">
  {% for post in collections.continents %}
    <li><a href="{{ post_url | post }}">{{ post.data.title}}</a></li>
  {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Is it possible to have a child collection of `continents`? For example `countries`? If so, where would this data need to be added to my theme?

It would be great to be able to then loop through the collections like this:

```
<ul class="parent-list">
  {% for post in collections.continents %}
    <li><a href="{{ post_url | post }}">{{ post.data.title}}</a></li>
    <ul class="child-list">
      {% for post in collections.countries %}
        <li><a href="{{ post_url | post }}">{{ post.data.title}}</a></li>
      {% endfor %}
    </ul>
  {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

I'm aware of [eleventy-navigation](https://github.com/11ty/eleventy-navigation) but it looks like you can only have one level of navigation with this too.

Comment: eleventy-navigation solves this exact problem and it does support N-level depth. Specifically as an example the sidebar on https://www.11ty.dev/docs/ shows 3 different levels

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, collections are only one level deep, so you can't do `collections.parent.child`. You could dynamically create collections such that you had collections.europe and collections.northamerica. You could then switch your second inner loop to something like this:

```
{% for post in collections.countries[post.data.title] %}
```

Does that make sense?

I should add, in order for this to work, your child posts should use front matter to set their parent, like: `continent: europe`

Comment: I'd also add - you can use directory structure as well, so for ex, /posts/europe/france.md and /posts/europe/spain.md. When looping over Europe, iterate over collections.all and see if the path matches.